# Why the "*.tif" file has very low size when I export the Sentinel-2 image to Google Drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I want to download a Sentinel-2 from Google Drive so I wrote the following code for this purpose,

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : image1 ,
  description: 'January',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry, 
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
```

But the image size in Google Drive is about 100 Kb! How can I resolve the problem? I saw a lot that satellite images have a size for example 40 Mb but don't know what is wrong in this case.

Comment: Probable reason could be specifying the geometry. If it is small, the whole tile is not downloaded. Hence, the image size is decreased.

Comment: @Padmanabha Thanks a lot! It is fixed now.